# Implementation of iterator protocol without __iter__ method in class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried with this code to implement iterator protocol, and every thing works fine.
Ideally it shouldn't as I have not implemeted `iter()`.

```
class PowerofTwo():
    def __init__(self,maxi):
        self.max = maxi
        self.num = 0     

    def __next__(self):
        if self.num < self.max:
            result = 2 ** self.num
            self.num += 1
            return result
        else:
            raise StopIteration


myObj = PowerofTwo(5)

print(type(myObj)) #print <class '__main__.PowerofTwo'>
print(next(myObj)) #print 1
```

Even if assume that `__iter__()` method is available by default like `__init__()`.
But not able to understand how can I directly call `next()` and skip calling `iter(obj)` at first place.
If I try same thing with list or other builtin iterator, I gets error that object is not an iterator.

Am I missing something basic here ?

Comment: `__next__` is exactly the method that the [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) function tries to call, and your class has a `__next__` method. Why do you expect it not to work?

Comment: `PowerofTwo` is an iterator, but it is *not* iterable. An iterable is something you can pass to `iter`; an iterator is the thing that `iter` returns and can be passed to `next`.

Comment: Some things, like the objects returned by `open`, are both iterable and iterators. Others, like `list`, are iterable, but not iterators. `iter([1,2,3])` returns not the list, but a value of type `list_iterator`.

Comment: @chepner What modifications are required to make PowerofTwo an iterable ?

Comment: You need to define `__iter__`, but it doesn't have to do anything other than return `self`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, `PowerofTwo` is an iterator, but it is not an iterable. To make it iterable, you need to define `__iter__` to return an object that has a `__next__` method. In this case, the instance of `PowerofTwo` itself will do.

```
class PowerofTwo:
    def __init__(self,maxi):
        self.max = maxi
        self.num = 0     

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.num < self.max:
            result = 2 ** self.num
            self.num += 1
            return result
        else:
            raise StopIteration


for x in PowerofTwo(5):
    print(x)
```

outputs

```
 1
 2
 4
 8
 16
```

It is considered good practice to always define

```
def __iter__(self):
    return self
```

in a class that defines `__next__`.

`list` is an example of a class whose `__iter__` method returns an instance of *another* class, namely `list_iterator`.